# toJson() removing text attribute when converting

Tags: react-native, webview, fabricjs

```
var text = new fabric.IText("hello world", { left: 10, top: 50});
canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();
canvas.getObjects();
canvas.toJSON().objects
```

below are image which shows the result of the above object and i have also tried to add a custom attribute and passed to canvas.toJSON(["attribute name"]) but the attribute was removed
Note the canvas is in webview and is a react native project

[getObjects result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB47b.png)
[toJson result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBm8Q.png)

Comment: just do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(canvas.getObjects()))`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: This works fine for me using their own examples--I think you're looking for the data in the wrong place. http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/7ev9pkwh/2/